# Using Spyder IDE to develop python for Grass GIS, get 'ImportError: No module named grass.script'

Tags: python, grass-gis, grass.script, importerror, spyder

I am trying to use Spyder IDE to develop a python script using python library from grass-6.4.3. I run the script below, and get

```
ImportError: No module named grass.script
```

I am using python 2.7, installed in Grass, Spyder, + native install (C:\python27) and my OS is 64-bit Windows 7.

This seems to be a common problem, but I have tried all the recommended fixes outlined below. I have even tried installing on a laptop running 32-bit windows 7 and get the same error.

I read the Grass wiki: page:https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python#External_Python_editors_.28IDE.29

Then I tried to follow this Q&A to the letter: [Problem with python script to control GRASS GIS from outside - How to import grass.script under Win 8.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89452/problem-with-python-script-to-control-grass-gis-from-outside-how-to-import-gra/90160#90160)

My python script:

```
import sys
import os

gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE'] = 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3'  
gisdbase = os.path.normpath('C:/Users/Ryan/grassdata')
location = 'newLocation'
mapset = 'Ryan'
GISRC = os.path.normpath('C:/Users/Ryan/AppData/Roaming/GRASS6/grassrc6')
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib'
PATH = 'C:\Python27';'C:\Users\Ryan\grassdata';'C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\GRASS6\grassrc6';'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\msys';'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\scripts'
PYTHONLIB = 'C:\Python27'
PYTHONPATH = 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python'
GRASS_SH = 'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\msys\bin\sh.exe'

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], 'etc', 'python'))
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W\bin')
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc') 
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python') 
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib') 
sys.path.append('C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin') 

import grass.script as grass
import grass.script.setup as gsetup

gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mapset)
```

I have added my environment variables manually into system settings (copied here):

```
GISBASE = C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3
GISDBASE = C:\Users\Ryan\grassdata
GISRC = C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\GRASS6\grassrc6
GRASS_SH = C:\OSGeo4W\apps\msys\bin\sh.exe
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib
PATH = C:\Python27;C:\Users\Ryan\grassdata;C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\GRASS6\grassrc6;C:\OSGeo4W64\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\msys;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\scripts
PYTHONLIB = C:\Python27
PYTHONPATH = C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python'
```

I have added a file called 'grass.pth' to: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27\lib\site-packages. The file contains:

`C:\OSGeo4W\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python
C:\OSGeo4W\bin`

I have started grass interactively to create a 'grassrc6' file, which is located here: C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Roaming\GRASS6\grassrc6

I am not sure what else I can try, I am certain something must be wrong with the environment variables, but I wouldn't know what to look for.

Also, is it necessary to define the environment variables in both the python script, and manually in system settings?

Comment: Do you have a chance to update to GRASS GIS 7? This comes with a completely rewritten and improved Python API: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/ - for a shortcourse, see https://github.com/wenzeslaus/python-grass-addon

Comment: Sorry for late reply.Ideally I would like this to work on the 6.x version as that is the end users current installation (using older python 2.x).

Comment: Maybe you can get help on the mailing list http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-dev/ (btw also GRASS GIS 7 works fine with Python 2.7 or later).

Answer (score 3):

This bat file starts spyder for me and imports grass.script fine:

```
@echo off
rem set OSGEO4W_ROOT=c:\OSGEO4W64
rem set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PATH%
call c:\osgeo4w64\bin\o4w_env.bat
call %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\env.bat
set GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdalplugins\1.9
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\lib
set PATH=%PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Scripts\
set GISBASE=C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3
set GISDBASE=d:\documents\grassdata
set GISRC=C:\Users\sando_000\AppData\Roaming\GRASS6\grassrc6
set GRASS_SH=C:\OSGeo4W\apps\msys\bin\sh.exe
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-6.4.3\etc\python
set QGISPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
start c:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Scripts\spyder.bat
```

I've got an OSGE4W 64bit installation w grass-6.4.3, python-2.7 and spyder installed from source package with:

```
python setup.py install
```

This script is a modified version from what used to start pyscripter with qgis:
https://mapoholic.wordpress.com/2012/06/28/configure-pyscripter-qgis/