# Import ESRI ASCII raster with python to GRASS

Tags: python, raster, grass-gis, ascii, grass-7.2

I had to get used to GRASS the last two days because I can't set up my python IDE to work with my osgeo4w python and I find it incredibly clunky. I have a simple ascii raster - I think its origin is ESRI ArcGIS given the following header structure:

```
ncols         389
nrows         265
xllcorner     665140
yllcorner     4823160
cellsize      20
NODATA_value  -9999
```

All I want to do is a simple import with the GRASS python editor to perform simple raster analyes. None of the 'Import raster data' menu entries worked out (probably because I can't flag the input type?), nor with the python editor. I tried to use [r.in.gdal](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.in.gdal.html):

```
import grass.script as grass
grass.run_command("r.in.gdal",
                input="AAIGrid_raster.asc",
                output="GRASS_raster.asc",
                flags="f")
```

But I don't know how to specify the import format (most likely AAIGrid), as the [description here](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library#Calling_a_GRASS_module_in_Python) doesn't help me sufficiently (btw. I think there are errors too on that page). In case I'd use `-f AAIGrid` in the shell, how does that look in pythonian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply read the GRASS GIS documentation. Thus, [r.in.gdal](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass73/manuals/r.in.gdal.html) specify that the result with the `flag 'f'` is

> List supported formats and exit

```
 grass.run_command("r.in.gdal",flags="f",input='/User/me/test.asc',output='test')
 Supported formats:
 GRASS (ro): GRASS Database Rasters (5.7+)
 PDF (rw): Geospatial PDF
 VRT (rw+): Virtual Raster
 GTiff (rw+): GeoTIFF
 ...
 AAIGrid (rw): Arc/Info ASCII Grid
 ...
```

Therefore, you don't need to specify that the original layer is an Arc/Info ASCII Grid (.asc), the format is detected automatically.

Simply use

```
grass.run_command("r.in.gdal",flags="o",input='/User/me/test.asc',output='test',overwrite=True)
```

or

```
grass.parse_command('r.in.gdal', flags='o', input='/User/me/test.asc',output='test', overwrite=True)
```

With:

-input = path/name of GDAL dataset to be imported
-output= name for output raster map (in Grass)
-flags="o" = Override projection check (use current location's projection)

You can also use [r.import](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.import.html)

```
grass.run_command("r.import",flags="o",input='/User/me/test.asc',output='test2',overwrite=True)
```

For the second question

> (I'd also highly appreciate guides on how to set up my windows cmd so I can use python with GRASS bindings...).

There are many answers in GIS SE, in the GRASS GIS Python library documentation ( [GRASS GIS Python scripting with script package](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/script.html#module-script.setup)), , in the GRASS GIS wiki ([Accessing GRASS modules without starting a GRASS session](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Accessing_GRASS_modules_without_starting_a_GRASS_session)), in ...

Comment: Very helpfull, thank you! Also I finally (!) figured out how to use QGIS and GRASS in my spyder IDE thanks to [this extremely underrated answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164258/50772) from user @csandor