# Spyder 3.2.6 does not work with GRASS GIS 7.2.2

Tags: grass-7.2, spyder

I've installed spyder 3.2.6 with pip from the OSGeo console. There is a spyder.exe file in `~\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Scripts` and the Spyder package directories show up in site-packages. If I run the executable, the IDE does not appear and there are no error outputs in the console. Visibly, absolutely nothing happens.

I've looked at

1. [Using Spyder IDE to develop python for Grass GIS, get 'ImportError: No module named grass.script'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159435/using-spyder-ide-to-develop-python-for-grass-gis-get-importerror-no-module-na?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [How to control QGIS from within Anaconda's Spyder (Continuum Analytics Python distribution) in Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143940/how-to-control-qgis-from-within-anacondas-spyder-continuum-analytics-python-di)

Following those exchanges, I do notice that I don't have a spyder.bat file, which I assumes just calls spyder.exe and some other things.

Has anyone else tried Spyder with the latest GRASS and had any success?